# Notify that certain value has changed in Dictionary

Tags: .net, wpf, dictionary, key, inotifypropertychanged

At the moment I'm writing my own dictionary that implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). See below:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

new public Item this[TKey key]
{
    get { return base.Item[key]; }
    set(TValue value)
    {
        if (base.Item[key] != value)
        {
            base.Item[key] = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("XXX"); // what string should I use?
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is simple: when a certain value in the Dictionary has changed, notify that it has changed. All WPF elements that have a binding with the corresponding key name should then update themselves.

Now my question is: what string should I use as `propertyName` in order to notify?

I have tried `"[" + key.ToString() + "]"`, `"Item[" + key.ToString() + "]"` and simply `key.ToString()`. They all did not seem to work, because the WPF elements did not update.

Using `String.Empty` (`""`) does update the WPF elements, but I'm not using this, because this will update all WPF elements that are bound the same dictionary, even though they have different keys.

---

This is how my binding looks like in XAML:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Dictionary}" Text="{Binding [Index]}" />
```

`Index` is of course the name of the key in my dictionary.

---

In stead of using INotifyPropertyChanged, some have suggested to use [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx). I tried this:

```
Dim index As Integer = MyBase.Keys.ToList().IndexOf(key)
Dim changedItem As Object = MyBase.ToList().ElementAt(index)

RaiseEvent CollectionChanged(Me, New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, changedItem, index))
```

**But that does not update the bound WPF elements either.**

Comment: Maybe [this code article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/12/26/observabledictionary-lt-tkey-tvalue-gt-c.aspx) helps?

Comment: @J.Steen, unfortunatelly, that implementation will notify **all** properties, even though only one changes. I'm looking for a cleaner way, that only updates the properties that actually have changed.

Comment: Dang. Well, worth a try. Sorry for taking your time. =)

Comment: I'm not sure this relates to the problem, but since you declare your indexer property using `new`, it will not be called by any code that accessed the dictionary through the `IDictionary<Key,Valye>` interface (or a base class reference).

Comment: @Olly, yes I realise that, and no that does not relate to the problem :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you need to consider the [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface rather than `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  If that's the case, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4964683/439024) and the blog post that it links to.

Also, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9393016/439024) to a previous question that was similar to yours.  It suggests that you use the value of [Binding.IndexerName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.indexername.aspx) as the property name for the change notification.

**Edit:**

If you want to avoid using `INotifyCollectionChanged`, you might try an alternative approach.  Change your dictionary so that the type of its values is a proxy object that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public class MyProxy<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public T Value
    {
        // Getter and setter with change notification code here.
    }
}
```

Then insert instances of this type into your dictionary just once.  Replace the code that updates a value in the dictionary with code that retrieves the proxy, then updates its `Value` property.

You would need to change your XAML binding to something like `([Item]).Value`.

After reviewing some of your other comments, it does look as though this approach might work for you.  It's similar to something I had to do recently.  Create a custom [KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx) and a corresponding proxy.  Add a `ItemName` property to the proxy; it can be read only, and does not need to support change notifications.  Make your `KeyedCollection` implementation index on the `ItemName` property.  Works a treat!  I'll add sample code if you would like it.

Comment: Nah, INotifyCollectionChanged does not care about property changes inside a collection. It'll only notify others when an item is added, removed, moved, replaced, or when the entire collection is reset. This interface is useful when binding to the entire collection to an `ItemsSource`, but it's not for my needs.

Comment: @Ruud, I've added a link to another post that might be useful.

Comment: I really appreciate your input, but unfortunatelly using `Binding.IndexerName` is the same as `"Item[]"`, which, as you can probably guess, will update **all** keys. I'm starting to think it is not possible to notify about changes *at a certain index/key*.

Comment: @RuudLenders - Hmm, I see your problem.  I really do think that this is closer to the `INotifyCollectionChanged` behavior than `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  In effect, when you change the value that corresponds to a given key, you are replacing an item in the `Dictionary.Values` collection.  That corresponds with the `Replace` member of the `NotifyCollectionChangedAction` enumeration.  The indexer property is, conceptually, just a convenient wrapper around these underlying collection structures.

Comment: @RuudLenders Your indexer implementation suggests that you want to send a notification when an item in the collection has been replaced (not when some property of the item has changed). `INotifyCollectionChanged` supports this case by raising a CollectionChanged event with an [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.action.aspx) value of `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace`.

Comment: @RuudLenders - Edited my answer with an alternative that doesn't involve `INotifyCollectionChanged`.  However, it would mean a bit more refactoring of your code.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you that `INotifyCollectionChanged` does not work as you said. However, I'll try the other suggestion you've put in your answer.

Comment: @RuudLenders - I suspect that for `INotifyCollectionChanged` to work, your dictionary class would also need to implement `ICollection<TValue>`.  But I think the 'proxy object' approach is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Olly, today I've succesfully implemented my `ObservableDictionary`, using your suggestion to use proxy objects. Many thanks for this wonderful suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (base.Item[key] != value)
{
     base.Item[key] = value;
     if (key == "notifykey") OnPropertyChanged("[Item]");
}
```

String.empty will notify all properties not just Item

Per op this as the problem of all the bindings to Dictionary still update.
So I would make a new property

Let just assume you value is string 
Bind to KeyedValue

```
public String KeyedValue
{
    get { return base.Item[Index]; }
}

if (key == "Index") OnPropertyChanged("KeyedValue");
```

Comment: Strangely, that does not work either. I'll update my answer so you can see how I set up the binding, maybe the problem comes from there.

Comment: Wow, OnPropertyChanged("") updates everything - correct?  Then there has to be a correct value.  A reach but try without the new.

Comment: `new` is required, because I'm inheriting the property from the `Dictionary` class itself. I found out that using `"Item[]"` as property name does work. However, that way bindings to other keys will also update.

Comment: Using properties is exactly what I'm trying to avoid at the moment :P I currently have 50+ properties, that's why I hoped using a `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` would make my code more simple.

Comment: I thought only had one KeyedValue and the other were simply not.  You should make that more clear in the question.   On a property you either fire Notify or not.  If you have 50+  bindings then I would just make 50+ properties.